# React Native save an image to iOS new photos album

Tags: react-native

I know there is `CameraRoll` and I'm currently using it as such:

```
CameraRoll.saveToCameraRoll(this.state.imageUrl)
  .then(console.log('Photo added to camera roll!'))
```

But what I really want to do is to create an album with my app name and put the photo in there.
Is it possible to do that with `CameraRoll` or using something else?

Comment: Have you found the solution for this? I am also struggling for the same

Comment: Anybody have idea ???